# Spark DataFrameに ネストしたJsonファイルからデータを読み込みたい

Tags: json, python3, spark

pysparkを使用しています。Spark 2.1以降であれば、スキーマ定義を行った後にJsonファイルを読み込むことができます。

---

例1
 test01.json

```
{
 "_id":"2d3erf5",
 "testNo":"0001",
 "Date":"2017-09-01 00:00:00.00000"
}
```

test01.py

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Spark SQL and DataFrame').getOrCreate()


testColumn = StructType([
  StructField('_id', StringType(), False),
  StructField('testNo', IntegerType(), False),
  StructField('Date', TimestampType(), False)
])
readFile = '/tmp/test01.json'
test_df = spark.read.json(readFile, schema=testColumn)
```

---

今回、ネストされているJsonファイルを読み込む必要があるのですが、どう記述すればよろしいのでしょうか？

---

例2
 test02.json

```
{
  "_id":"2d3erf5",
  "testNo":"0001",
  "test_date"{
              "date_1":"2017-09-01 00:00:00.00000",
              "date_2":"2017-09-05 03:00:00.00000"
             }
}
```

以下のような感じに記述するのかなとは、思っていますが、どなたかご教授願います。

test02.py

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Spark SQL and DataFrame').getOrCreate() 


testColumn = StructType([
  StructField('_id', StringType(), False),
  StructField('testNo', IntegerType(), False),
  StructField('test_date.date_1', TimestampType(), False),
  StructField('test_date.date_2', TimestampType(), False),
])
readFile = '/tmp/test02.json'
test_df = spark.read.json(readFile, schema=testColumn)
```

Answer (score 1):

ネストしたスキーマは次のように定義します

```
testColumn = StructType([
  StructField('_id', StringType(), False),
  StructField('testNo', IntegerType(), False),
  StructField('test_date',
              StructType([
                  StructField('date_1', TimestampType(), False),
                  StructField('date_2', TimestampType(), False)
              ]), False)
])
```

selectを使って特定のフィールドだけ選択します。

```
test_df = spark.read.json(readFile, schema=testColumn)
x = test_df.select('_id', 'test_date.date_1')
x.show()
```